# Cannot verify my website for Google Adsense

Tags: google-adsense

My website address is https://tora.us.fm. When I try to add it to My Google AdSense console, I get the following error:

[image]

So I add `us.fm` instead. But then I am asked to verify it by adding an `ads.txt` file at the root. I do this, but Google cannot find this file --- probably because it looks at https://us.fm/ads.txt rather than at https://tora.us.fm/ads.txt :

[image]

How can I have my real site https://tora.us.fm verified?

Answer (score 2):

Adsense requires you demonstrate control of the domain. Control of all sub-domains is then assumed. The TLD is `.fm` not `.us.fm` therefore it is the domain `us.fm` that must be verified.

Once a domain is verified, the domain or any sub-domain can be used as part of that adsense account.

If you do not control the domain you cannot perform the verification.

Comment: I do not control the domain, because only the subdomain was for sale.

Comment: Not sure what it really means to "buy" a sub-domain given the way TLDs work. You have your answer though.  Whoever "sold" you the sub-domain is the owner of the sub-domain as far as the Internet is concerned.  This might be better in chat but a URL to the "registrar" that "sold" you the sub-domain would be helpful on this seperate issue. I imagine there a legal gotchas and risk for both the "buyer" and the "seller"